# How to compare two lists using apache freemarker?

Tags: freemarker

I can compare basic values with

```
<#if myvar=="value">do something..</#if>
```

But it doesn't support lists.

I didn't find any 'compare' like function in the documentation : https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_sequence.html

Comment: Better do it in yout program code rather than template code, I would say.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't have such functionality (as of 2.3.29). You need to write a `#function` for it, if you really need to do this inside the template.